# Не работают точки останова в MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, linux-mint, monodevelop

Суть проблемы такая - есть класс на C#, метод которого нужно отладить. Я в MonoDevelop 7.5(build 1255) ставлю точку останова. Когда я запускаю отладку, программа выполняется и не тормозится там где нужно. Как быть в этом случае?

P.S. точка останова вызывается на методе LeftRotate

ОС: Linux Mint 18.3 64bit

IDE: MonoDevelop 7.5

```
using System;

namespace RBTrees
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public enum BinSide
        {
            Left,
            Right
        }
        public enum Color
        {
            Black,
            Red
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Бинарное дерево поиска
        /// </summary>
        public class BinaryTree
        {

            public long? Data { get; private set; }
            public BinaryTree Left { get; set; }
            public BinaryTree Right { get; set; }
            public BinaryTree Parent { get; set; }
            public Color T_Color { get; set; }
            public BinaryTree Root { get; set; } // указатель на корень дерева. Нужен для того, чтобы при поворотах не потерять корень дерева.

            /// <summary>
            /// Вставляет целочисленное значение в дерево
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data">Значение, которое добавится в дерево</param>
            public void Insert(long data)
            {
                if (Data == null || Data == data)
                {
                    Data = data;
                    T_Color = Color.Black;
                    return;
                }
                if (Data > data)
                {
                    if (Left == null) Left = new BinaryTree();
                    Insert(data, Left, this);
                    /*if (this.T_Color == Color.Black) Left.T_Color = Color.Red;
                    if (this.T_Color == Color.Red) Left.T_Color = Color.Black;*/

                }
                else
                {
                    if (Right == null) Right = new BinaryTree();
                    Insert(data, Right, this);
                    /*if (this.T_Color == Color.Black) Left.T_Color = Color.Red;
                    if (this.T_Color == Color.Red) Left.T_Color = Color.Black;*/
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Вставляет значение в определённый узел дерева
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data">Значение</param>
            /// <param name="node">Целевой узел для вставки</param>
            /// <param name="parent">Родительский узел</param>
            private void Insert(long data, BinaryTree node, BinaryTree parent)
            {

                if (node.Data == null || node.Data == data)
                {
                    node.Data = data;
                    node.Parent = parent;
                    if (parent.T_Color == Color.Black) node.T_Color = Color.Red;
                    if (parent.T_Color == Color.Red) node.T_Color = Color.Black;
                    return;
                }
                if (node.Data > data)
                {
                    if (node.Left == null) node.Left = new BinaryTree();
                    Insert(data, node.Left, node);
                    if (parent.T_Color == Color.Black) Left.T_Color = Color.Red;
                    if (parent.T_Color == Color.Red) Left.T_Color = Color.Black;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.Right == null) node.Right = new BinaryTree();
                    Insert(data, node.Right, node);
                    if (parent.T_Color == Color.Black) Right.T_Color = Color.Red;
                    if (parent.T_Color == Color.Red) Right.T_Color = Color.Black;
                }
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Уставляет узел в определённый узел дерева
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data">Вставляемый узел</param>
            /// <param name="node">Целевой узел</param>
            /// <param name="parent">Родительский узел</param>
            private void Insert(BinaryTree data, BinaryTree node, BinaryTree parent)
            {

                if (node.Data == null || node.Data == data.Data)
                {
                    node.Data = data.Data;
                    node.Left = data.Left;
                    node.Right = data.Right;
                    node.Parent = parent;
                    return;
                }
                if (node.Data > data.Data)
                {
                    if (node.Left == null) node.Left = new BinaryTree();
                    Insert(data, node.Left, node);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.Right == null) node.Right = new BinaryTree();
                    Insert(data, node.Right, node);
                }
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Определяет, в какой ветви для родительского лежит данный узел
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="node"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private BinSide? MeForParent(BinaryTree node)
            {
                if (node.Parent == null) return null;
                if (node.Parent.Left == node) return BinSide.Left;
                if (node.Parent.Right == node) return BinSide.Right;
                return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Удаляет узел из дерева
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="node">Удаляемый узел</param>
            public void Remove(BinaryTree node)
            {
                if (node == null) return;
                var me = MeForParent(node);
                //Если у узла нет дочерних элементов, его можно смело удалять
                if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null)
                {
                    if (me == BinSide.Left)
                    {
                        node.Parent.Left = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.Parent.Right = null;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                //Если нет левого дочернего, то правый дочерний становится на место удаляемого
                if (node.Left == null)
                {
                    if (me == BinSide.Left)
                    {
                        node.Parent.Left = node.Right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.Parent.Right = node.Right;
                    }

                    node.Right.Parent = node.Parent;
                    return;
                }
                //Если нет правого дочернего, то левый дочерний становится на место удаляемого
                if (node.Right == null)
                {
                    if (me == BinSide.Left)
                    {
                        node.Parent.Left = node.Left;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.Parent.Right = node.Left;
                    }

                    node.Left.Parent = node.Parent;
                    return;
                }

                //Если присутствуют оба дочерних узла
                //то правый ставим на место удаляемого
                //а левый вставляем в правый

                if (me == BinSide.Left)
                {
                    node.Parent.Left = node.Right;
                }
                if (me == BinSide.Right)
                {
                    node.Parent.Right = node.Right;
                }
                if (me == null)
                {
                    var bufLeft = node.Left;
                    var bufRightLeft = node.Right.Left;
                    var bufRightRight = node.Right.Right;
                    node.Data = node.Right.Data;
                    node.Right = bufRightRight;
                    node.Left = bufRightLeft;
                    Insert(bufLeft, node, node);
                }
                else
                {
                    node.Right.Parent = node.Parent;
                    Insert(node.Left, node.Right, node.Right);
                }
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Удаляет значение из дерева
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data">Удаляемое значение</param>
            public void Remove(long data)
            {
                var removeNode = Find(data);
                if (removeNode != null)
                {
                    Remove(removeNode);
                }
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Ищет узел с заданным значением
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data">Значение для поиска</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public BinaryTree Find(long data)
            {
                if (Data == data) return this;
                if (Data > data)
                {
                    return Find(data, Left);
                }
                return Find(data, Right);
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Ищет значение в определённом узле
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data">Значение для поиска</param>
            /// <param name="node">Узел для поиска</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public BinaryTree Find(long data, BinaryTree node)
            {
                if (node == null) return null;

                if (node.Data == data) return node;
                if (node.Data > data)
                {
                    return Find(data, node.Left);
                }
                return Find(data, node.Right);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Количество элементов в дереве
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public long CountElements()
            {
                return CountElements(this);
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Количество элементов в определённом узле
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="node">Узел для подсчета</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private long CountElements(BinaryTree node)
            {
                long count = 1;
                if (node.Right != null)
                {
                    count += CountElements(node.Right);
                }
                if (node.Left != null)
                {
                    count += CountElements(node.Left);
                }
                return count;
            }
            public void RotateLeft(BinaryTree node, BinaryTree parent)
            {
                BinaryTree _a = new BinaryTree();
                BinaryTree _b_dLeft = new BinaryTree();
                BinaryTree _b = new BinaryTree();
                _b = node.Right;
                _b_dLeft = node.Right.Left;
                _a = node;
                node = _b;
                node.Left = _a;
                node.Left.Right = _b_dLeft;
                parent.Left = node;
            }
            private void RotateRight(BinaryTree node)
            {

            }
        }

        public class BinaryTreeExtensions
        {
            public static void Print(BinaryTree node)
            {
                if (node != null)
                {
                    if (node.Parent == null)
                    {
                        Console.Write("ROOT:{0}", node.Data);
                        if (node.T_Color == Color.Red) Console.WriteLine(" Red");
                        else Console.WriteLine(" Black");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (node.Parent.Left == node)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Left for {1}  --> {0}", node.Data, node.Parent.Data);
                            if (node.T_Color == Color.Red) Console.WriteLine(" Red");
                            else Console.WriteLine(" Black");
                        }

                        if (node.Parent.Right == node)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Right for {1} --> {0}", node.Data, node.Parent.Data);
                            if (node.T_Color == Color.Red) Console.WriteLine(" Red");
                            else Console.WriteLine(" Black");
                        }
                    }
                    if (node.Left != null)
                    {
                        Print(node.Left);
                    }
                    if (node.Right != null)
                    {
                        Print(node.Right);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tree = new BinaryTree();
            /*tree.Insert(20);
            tree.Insert(40);
            tree.Insert(10);
            tree.Insert(30);
            tree.Insert(80);
            tree.Insert(29);
            tree.Insert(31);
            tree.Insert(32);
            tree.Insert(70);*/
            tree.Insert(10);
            tree.Insert(20);
            tree.Insert(30);
            tree.RotateLeft(tree.Right, tree);
            tree.Insert(40);
            tree.Insert(50);
            tree.Insert(60);
            tree.Insert(70);

            BinaryTreeExtensions.Print(tree);
            /*tree.Remove(40);
            BinaryTreeExtensions.Print(tree);
            tree.Remove(20);
            BinaryTreeExtensions.Print(tree);*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы указали все, кроме главного - кода

Comment: Может просто программа не доходит до точки останова?

Comment: Нет. Она доходит до неё. Маркер тому тот факт, что 30 пропадает из дерева - элемент теряется в ходе, видимо, неверной работы метода.

Comment: Более того, установка точки останова на другое место так же не принесла плодов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока проблема решилась установкой маркера в зоне Main. Странное поведение... Или я просто привык что Visual Studio тормозится на точках поставленных на конкретных методах...